# how to select values from two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `arts` and `artsdetails`.. `artsId` is the primary key in `arts` table foreign key in `artdetails` table. I am selecting values from both table but my query is giving error as

> "Invalid object name 'artdetails'"

My query is:

```
SELECT arts.artsId, artdetails.mainImage
FROM artdetails 
INNER JOIN arts ON artdetails.artsId = arts.artsId;
```

Please help.

Comment: Are they both in the `dbo` schema?

Comment: `artdetais` or `artsdetails` whichone??

Comment: I think @NagarajS means `artsdetails` or `artdetails` (not artdetais comment) (one in OP body has arts...) SQL OP has  `artdetails`  is it a simple matter of missing an s on art ***s*** details table?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not running the query in the database where these tables live.

If you're using SQL Server Management studio, look in the top left for a drop down containing the database names. It probably says 'master' (as that's the default). Select the one containing the tables you're using and re-run your query.

Failing that, check they're both running in the same schema as Tom suggests.

You can fully quality table names in your query like this:

```
SELECT a.artsId, ads.mainImage
FROM [DBNAME].[SCHEMA].artdetails ad
INNER JOIN [DBNAME].[SCHEMA].arts a ON ad.artsId = a.artsId;
```

Also using table abbreviations tidies things up a bit.

Comment: hey thank you.I have not selected database name.it was master.This solved my problem

Comment: You're welcome. If it's helped you, please upvote my answer using the up arrow and click the tick beneath to "accept" it and show you've found your answer.